# OCMOCK testing block

Tags: ios, objective-c-blocks, ocmock, bolts-framework

I am using the bolt framework for an Async task. How do I test the code, which is in continueWithBlock section?

```
BOOL wasFetchedFromCache;
   [[store fetchFileAsync:manifestURL allowfetchingFromCache:YES fetchedFromCache:&wasFetchedFromCache]
        continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
            NSData *fileContents = task.result;
            NSError *localError;

            // code to test
            return nil
        }];
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to test async task, you should use XCTestExpectation which allows us to create an expectation that will be fulfilled in the future. That mean the future results returned is considered as an expectation in the test case, and the test will wait until receiving the results for asserted. Please take a look at the code below, which I write a simple async testing.

```
- (void)testFetchFileAsync {
    XCTestExpectation *expectation = [self expectationWithDescription:@"FetchFileAsync"];
    BOOL wasFetchedFromCache;
    [[store fetchFileAsync:manifestURL allowfetchingFromCache:YES fetchedFromCache:&wasFetchedFromCache]
     continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
         NSData *data = task.result;
         NSError *localError;

         XCTAssertNotNil(data, @"data should not be nil");

         [expectation fulfill];
         // code to test
         return nil
     }];

    [self waitForExpectationsWithTimeout:15.0 handler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Timeout error");
        }
    }];

    XCTAssertTrue(wasFetchedFromCache, @"should be true");
}
```